# Unable to install forecast package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, forecast

When I run the following commmand:

```
  install.packages('forecast', dependencies = TRUE)
  library(forecast)
```

I get the error:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called ‘ggplot2’ In
>   addition: Warning message: package ‘forecast’ was built under R
>   version 3.2.5  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’

Anyone has had the same problem? I am using R Studio Version 1.1.456

Answer (score 0):

Try installing (or reinstalling) `ggplot2`.

```
remove.packages(ggplot2)
install.packages(ggplot2, dependencies = TRUE)
```